# Delete an instance from its class' dict in desctructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, del

I'm trying to create a class that saves all of its instances in a dictionary:

```
>>> class X:
    def __new__(cls, index):
        if index in cls._instances:
            return cls._instances[index]
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        self.index = index
        cls._instances[index] = self
        return self
    def __del__(self):
        del type(self)._instances[self.index]
    _instances = {}
```

However, the `__del__` doesn't seem to work:

```
>>> x = X(1)
>>> del x
>>> X._instances
{1: <__main__.X object at 0x00000000035166D8>}
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on Kirk Strauser's answer, I'd like to point out that, when you `del x`, the class' `_instances` still holds *another* reference to `x` - and thus it can't be garbage collected (and `__del__` won't run.

Instead of doing this kind of low-level magic, you probably should be using [`weakref`s](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html), which were implemented especially for this purpose.

[WeakValueDictinary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakValueDictionary), in particular, suits your needs perfectly, and you can fill it on `__init__` instead of fiddling with `__new__` and `__del__`

Comment: I haven't had occasion to use weakrefs, but I'm reading that a "weak reference to an object is not enough to keep the object alive: when the only remaining references to a referent are weak references, garbage collection is free to destroy the referent and reuse its memory for something else."

Could that be a problem if he explicitly wants to track each item?

Comment: @KirkStrauser yes, indeed. But then, why he is he removing the instances from the dictionary on `__del__`?

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong, but `__del__` isn't quite what you think. From [the docs on it](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__):

> **Note** `del x` doesn’t directly call `x.__del__()` — the former decrements the reference count for `x` by one, and the latter is only called when `x`‘s reference count reaches zero.

Running this from the interpreter is particularly tricky because command history or other mechanisms may hold references to `x` for an indeterminate amount of time.

By the way, your code looks an awful lot like a defaultdict with `X` as the factory. It may be more straightforward to use something like that to be more explicit (ergo more Pythonic) about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Oh damn it... Is there a fix (edit: workaround) for this then? Can I directly just call `__del__` on an object and have it do essentially the same thing?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen See my edit about using an explicit data structure to contain your `X` instances rather than `X` attempting to do it itself. If you're explicitly calling `__del__` then you might as well spell it `del x_dict[index]`.